# Angular LazyLoading with multiple component doesn't work

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I am new in Angular. I am trying to implement lazy loading with multiple component. Its lazy load home component properly but it fails to load another components.

It throws below error:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'admin'

**app.routing.ts**

```
{
   path: '',
   component: SiteLayoutComponent,
   children: 
   [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: './lazymodules/lazy.module#LazyModule',
      },
   ]},
```

**lazy-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: HomeComponent,
  }
   ,
   {
     path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent,
   },
  { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent }];
```

I have created similar sample application on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vlrctw?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts&hideNavigation=1). Anybody please hep here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your navigation code (In site header file) with -

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/home/admin');
```

or

```
this.router.navigate(['home/admin']);
```

Comment: Hi Pradeep Sir, Thanks for the answers. It works. But in this code my url has been changed from http://localhost:61801/admin to  http://localhost:61801/home/admin. Can we achieve this with the same url like 'http://localhost:61801/admin' or 'http://localhost:61801/about'?

Comment: Offcourse but for that you need to change routing configurtion.

Comment: Could you please share the possible routing configuration for the same. It will help me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the below changes I made in the `site-header.component.ts`

```
NavigateToRoute(pageURL: string) {
    //alert(pageURL);
    if (pageURL == "home") {
      console.log(pageURL);
      this.router.navigate(['home']),
      this.MenuActive = "home";
    }
    else if (pageURL == "admin") {
      console.log(pageURL);
      this.router.navigate(['admin'], {relativeTo: this.route}); // <- this was missing
      this.MenuActive = "admin";
    }
    else if (pageURL == "settings") {
      console.log(pageURL);
      this.router.navigate(['settings'], {relativeTo: this.route});
      this.MenuActive = "settings";
    }
    else if (pageURL == "about") {
      console.log(pageURL);
      this.router.navigate(['about'], {relativeTo: this.route});
      this.MenuActive = "about";
    }
    else if (pageURL == "login") {
      console.log(pageURL);
      this.router.navigate(['login'], {relativeTo: this.route});
    }
  }
```

Have a look at the updated example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pa4q9c)